# NSSet & NSCountedSet object differentiation

Tags: ios, nsset, nscountedset

I am working with `NSSet` and `NSCountedSet` and I have a question about how NSSet differentiate the object?
Is it using the memory location? If I had 2 objects named `car1` and I got the one from an array and the other downloaded from Internet will be considered as one object if are exact the same? 
Going through **Apple's** documentation didn't explained the above case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSSet` use `hash` and `isEqual` method to determine objects equality. If you didn't override this two methods Foundation will use methods from `NSObject`. Mike Ash has a [good article](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-06-18-implementing-equality-and-hashing.html) about hash and isEqual.